# patronictl showing no members

Tags: postgresql, patroni

I have a 3 node cluster of postgresql running normally using patroni, however when trying to run
/usr/bin/patronictl -c /etc/patroni/patroni.yml list

it shows

- Cluster: pg_cluster (uninitialized) ----------+
  | Member | Host | Role | State | TL | Lag in MB |
  +--------+------+------+-------+----+-----------+
  +--------+------+------+-------+----+-----------+

although pg_cluster  was actually initialized, what could be the reason?

Comment: Also, I am able to get the members using REST APIs

Answer (score 0):

Turned out its due to etcd version patronictl is using. etcd3 needs to be mentioned in case cluster is build using etcd3

```
patronictl -c /etc/patroni/patroni.yml --dcs-url "etcd3://x.x.x.x:2379" list
```